# What is wrong with my recursive C function?

Tags: c, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I have a little C program.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void counter(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    counter(n);
    return 0;
}

void counter(int n)
{  
    printf("%d\n", n);

    if(n == 0) {
        return;
    }

    counter(n - 1);
}
```

When I enter 200000 as the command line argument it works well. But with 300000 it says: 17623 segmentation fault (core dumped).

With gdb, the error is: Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a6f198 in _IO_new_file_write (f=0x7ffff7dd0760 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>, data=0x555555756260, n=6) at fileops.c:1196 1196 fileops.c: No such file or directory.

I don't know what is wrong. Should I allocate memory or something like that?

Comment: A stack overflow might be manifesting as a segfault. Trying to recurse 300k times is a little excessive. If a function needs to recurse that many times, it probably shouldn't be recursive.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Why not? The function is fully tail recursive, as long as we can guarantee tail calling there’s no reason whatsoever to make it less readable by manually rewriting it into an iterative variant. And effectively we *can* guarantee this in C.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, maybe some option must be enabled to have the compiler tun the tail recursion into a loop?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, optimisations must be enabled. Not sure if you were intending to reply to me, since I don’t think this relates to what I said.

Comment: Tail recursion optimization is not required by C.  Code simply ran out of (stack) memory.

Comment: @KonradRudolph *as long as we can guarantee tail calling [optimization]*. Yes, if that can be guarenteed, by all means. If not though, you have a time bomb.